# How can the roles for individual users be listed, selected and edited with membership info

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to create an admin section to manage users using .net MVC3 in vs 2010. I've figured out how to create and edit new users and roles separately. But I am struggling to figure out how to add roles when I create or edit a new user. This is as far as I've gotten:

In my Model:

```
public class UserModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; } 
}
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

In my Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{        
    return View(
        new IndexViewModel
        {
            Users = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>().Select(x => new UserModel
            {
                UserName = x.UserName,
                Email = x.Email,
            }),
            Roles = Roles.GetAllRoles()
        });
}
```

And in the View:

```
@model IEnumerable<BBmvc.Areas.Tools.Models.IndexViewModel>
//...
@foreach (var item in Model) {
 foreach (var user in item.Users)
 {
  <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.UserName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.Email)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.Password)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.ConfirmPassword)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=user.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=user.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=user.PrimaryKey */ })
    </td>
  </tr>
 }
}
```

I am seeing this error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'BBmvc.Areas.Tools.Models.IndexViewModel', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

I'm confused. Am I on the right track? Right now I'm simply trying to get the roles to display on the page ... eventually I need them to be filtered for each user so that only the roles a user is in will be listed.

**EDIT:**
The answer below fixed the viewmodel problem I was having. The ultimate solution to displaying roles for each user wasn't that involved. I added a list to the UserModel:

```
public IEnumerable<string> UserRoles { get; set; }
```

Filled it in the Controller:

```
        public ActionResult Index2()
    {
        var model = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>().Select(x => new UserModel
        {
            UserName = x.UserName,
            Email = x.Email,
            UserRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(x.UserName)
        });
        return View(model);
    }
```

And then displayed it in the view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
    </td>
    <td>
        @foreach (var role in item.UserRoles)
        {
            @role
        }
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: What is the "@model" on your view?

Comment: @model IEnumerable<BBmvc.Areas.Tools.Models.IndexViewModel>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are returning just 1 object of type `IndexViewModel` you need to change your `@model` to `@model BBmvc.Areas.Tools.Models.IndexViewModel`.

As this single object is holding a list of users and roles... you need to change the view:

```
 @model BBmvc.Areas.Tools.Models.IndexViewModel
 //...    
 @foreach (var user in Model.Users)
 {
          <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.UserName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.Password)
            </td>
            <td>
                @foreach (var role in Model.Roles.Where(x => x.idUser == user.idUser))
                {
                    <span>@role.Name</span> |
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("ViewRoles", "View Roles", new { id=user.PrimaryKey }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=user.PrimaryKey }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=user.PrimaryKey }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=user.PrimaryKey })
            </td>
          </tr>
 }
```

This way, you can have the roles of the user, and clicking on "*View Roles*" or "*Setup Roles*" (use the link text that best suite your problem) you can have a list of the roles of that user. There you can add/edit/delete roles for the selected user.

Comment: That is much better. How do I get from here to displaying the roles specific to each user?

Comment: @Rob, you can have a View to display Roles, and place another link in this one:  '@Html.ActionLink("ViewRoles", "View Roles", new { id=user.PrimaryKey })'.  Besides that, you can have a Roles summary in other '<td>' of this table. See update.

Comment: I actually added the list of roles to the UserModel:

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `@model`

From: `@model IEnumerable<BBmvc.Areas.Tools.Models.IndexViewModel>`

To: `@model BBmvc.Areas.Tools.Models.IndexViewModel`.

The code in your controller is just returning an instance of `IndexViewModel`, not an `IEnumerable` (in other words a collection/list/array/whatever) of `IndexViewModel`'s.